# Setting up Azure to auto restart when server crashes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to set azure to automatically restart the server/website when it goes down with the 502/503 error? We've been encountering this a few times this week and had to go in to manually restart the app. We're still investigating the issue, but it'd be nice to have it automatically go back up.

We saw the autoheal feature, but it looks like that's enabled by default.

Comment: When application goes down, it should cold start automatically when the serve receives a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another feature along with the Auto Heal (you set triggers), that’s Proactive Auto Heal.

From the issue description, there some confusion (We saw the auto heal feature, but it looks like that's enabled by default), just trying to clarify if your requirement can be achieved by Auto Heal or you don’t want to use that?

You simply define the triggers (503) in the root web.config file of your website and configure the actions (restart worker process) to be performed when these triggers are hit. For this, take a look at Scenario 4 – “Taking custom actions (or recycling/logging) based on memory limit” – here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/

Proactive Auto Heal is automatically enabled it by default, it will take corrective actions for the sites that we have deemed to be in a bad state (Percent Memory Rule and/or Percent Request Rule) for which the best way to recover is to simply restart the Web App. See, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/17/proactive-auto-heal/ for details.

Comment: Ah I okay that makes sense. I had misunderstood what AutoHeal does. I thought it would restart the server anytime it crashes. But It looks like I have to set triggers for 502/503 right?

Comment: Is this auto-healing feature still active?
I have an **App Service** on **Standard Tier** and I'm able to see **Diagnostics** and drill down for instance on `5xx Errors`  but I'm not able to see or access any `auto-healing` option.

Comment: I finally found **AutoHeal**. 
You can find it under your specific App service. Then **Diagnose and solve problems**. Then under **Diagnostic Tools** tile, you have **AutoHeal**.

There you can find **Auto Healing** .
Once in there, **configure MItigation Rules** (which define triggers) and **Proactive Auto-Healing** enabled by default.
This is a more [updated link](https://stack247.wordpress.com/2019/05/20/azure-app-service-auto-healing/)


**PS**: In my case, I'm not able/don't know how to edit web.config.  Each time I edit it I get a 409 error and my changes are not saved.